# Problem With Constructors With Parameters In PHP

Tags: php

```
class MyClass {
  function __constructor($A,$B,$C) {
    echo("$A $B $C");
  }
}
$MC=new MyClass('Hello','World','!');
```

My parameters don't seem to be making it through to the constructor... Am I doing this wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its `__construct()`

```
class MyClass {
  function __construct($A,$B,$C) {
    echo("$A $B $C");
  }
}
$MC=new MyClass('Hello','World','!');
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php#language.oop5.decon.constructor

Comment: Additionally, if you are used to C++ or C#, you can also use name of the class as the name of constructor.

Comment: Oops!  How Embarrassing!  Thanks!