# How do I define a constructor in a PHP class?

Tags: php

Please help me to find out how to define constructors in PHP classes.

I wrote a class in such way:

```
class ABC
{
private $x=5;
function display()
{
echo $this->x;
}
}
```

Now I'm trying to define a parametrized constructor to the class thus I can create object with proper value to $x.  How can I do that?

Comment: http://us.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2534174/problem-with-constructors-with-parameters-in-php?rq=1

Answer (score 3):

[constructor documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php)

```
class ABC
{
  private $x;

  function __construct($x)
  {
    $this->x = $x;
  }

  function display()
  {
    echo $this->x;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Although it has been correctly answered by the other two (sorry too lazy to say your names :P), it has to be said that you could also write your constructor like this:

```
<?php
// Constructor
class Object {
    function Object($vars) {

    }
}
?>
```

Constructors can also be given the same name as the class itself, it doesn't always have to be `__construct()`

> **Update from [official documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php)**
>   **Warning**
>   Old style constructors are DEPRECATED in PHP 7.0, and will be removed in a future version. You should always use __construct() in new code.

Comment: Thanks for showing both versions of constructors. +1

Answer (score 2):

Check out this documentation link: http://us.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php

```
 <?php

 /**
   * a class demonstrating constructors
   *
   */

 class ABC
 {
    var $x;

    public function __construct($arg)
    {
         // this function gets its arguments via the class constructor
         $this->x = $arg;

    }
    public function showVariable()
    {

         echo $this->x;

    }

 }
 ?>


<?php
 // see the class constructor can take an argument (to be passed to the __construct) function 
 // it can be an array or just a variable

 $abc = new ABC("Hello World");
 $abc->showVariable();

 ?>
```